# generate exact clock time in seconds and express time zone offset as well

Tags: java, hl7, ccd

I am generating Continuity Of Care document that requires effective time. The document states:

```
CONF-9:     ClinicalDocument / effectiveTime SHALL be expressed with precision to include seconds.
CONF-10:    ClinicalDocument / effectiveTime SHALL include an explicit time zone offset.
```

Well, I can get current time in seconds:

```
long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis);
```

But I have no idea what the second part says about having time zone. A example of correct effective time would be `20000407130000+0500`. It is from one of the sample.

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is UTC by definition.

From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())

> the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

Just hard code UTC as the time zone for your timestamps.